# Why isn't $\log(-1)$ defined?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, logarithms

Why isn't $\log(-1)$ defined?

It can be defined as being equal to $i\pi$. Why don't we define the $\log$ function over Complex Numbers as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logarithm is defined for complex numbers too. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm
It is multivalued function. One of values of $\log(-1)$ is $i\pi$.

Comment: Thanks! When I gave this explanation in class today my teacher said that I was talking nonsense.

Comment: Well... It *is* nonsense until you define precisely what you are talking about, and it requires a fair amount of complex analysis. You can't simply jump to *a* value of $\log(-1)$: before, you need to extend the $\log$ function to complex argument, and to explain whay you can't have a continuous function on the whole plane, hence branch cuts and multivalued functions, etc.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: On the whole plane we can’t only because log *x* → −∞ for real *x* → +0. More interesting question is why can’t we have a continuous single-valued logarithm on ℂ\{0}.